# How to upgrade skype 4.0 to skype 4.2

Tags: 11.10, skype

I am using ubuntu 11.10 64-bit. I am currently using skype 4.0 and i want to upgrade my skype to 4.2. Do let me know the way to upgrade my skype

Comment: Have a look at my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/299819/does-anyone-else-have-problems-with-the-new-version-of-skype-4-2-0-11), it might help you.

Comment: *"I am using ubuntu 11.10 64-bit."* Ubuntu Oneiric is end-of-life. Newer software versions won't be available generally. Please upgrade to a supported release.

Answer (score 1):

1. First remove skype using ubuntu software center.
2. Install Gdebi Package Installer using ubuntu software center.
3. Download latest skype for ubuntu from its official website.
4. Install the downloaded skype file using Gdebi package installer.

Answer (score 0):

1. First add the repository `sudo add-apt-repository "deb
   http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"`
2. Then run the following command `sudo apt-get update` to check for updates.
3. Finally you can install the latest version by running `sudo apt-get
   install skype`