# Unable to install Skype in Ubunutu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, skype

I downloaded Skype for Ubuntu from [here](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/%E2%80%8E). I tried to install it with the command `sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb` but the installation failed. The following lines were displayed in the terminal:

```
dineshkumar@dineshkumar-desktop:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package skype.
(Reading database ... 169017 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking skype (from skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:
 skype depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36); however:
  Package libqtwebkit4 is not installed.
 skype depends on libxss1; however:
  Package libxss1 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype
```

Why did the installation fail and how could I install Skype from the .deb file that I have?

I checked the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299819/does-anyone-else-have-problems-with-the-new-version-of-skype-4-2-0-11/301000#301000) but found it of no use. The problem being discussed there was about Skype malfunctioning after an update. But in my case, I couldn't even install Skype properly.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/299819/does-anyone.-else-have-problems-with-the-new-version-of-skype-4-2-0-11/301000#301000), see if it helps in installing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by dependency problems (absence of some packages which skype requires for it to be installed). The following lines that were displayed confirm this:

```
skype depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36); however:
  Package libqtwebkit4 is not installed.
skype depends on libxss1; however:
  Package libxss1 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing skype (--install):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Therefore, it is obvious that the error can be overcome by installing the missing packages (`libqtwebkit4` & `libxss1`). To install these packages,

- Open the Terminal.
- Type `sudo apt-get install libqtwebkit4` to install the libqtwebkit4 package.
- Type `sudo apt-get install libxss1` to install the libxss1 package.
- After installing the required packages, continue with the process of installing skype with the command `sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb`

Answer (score 0):

you can install skype using command line by:

```
wget -O skype-NoobsLab.deb http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-lucid_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i skype-NoobsLab.deb

sudo apt-get -f install
```

**For 64Bit**

Terminal Commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

sudo apt-get update

wget -O skype-NoobsLab.deb http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-lucid_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i skype-NoobsLab.deb

sudo apt-get -f install;rm skype-NoobsLab.deb
```

After all of this run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

This will restore the skype contact window

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skype
```